# Has anyone else had weird visual artifacts appear on perfectly normal faces when baking textures in blender render?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, artifacts

I'm trying to bake a UV texture of multiple materials in blender render. 
All faces in the UV editor are organized and separated enough that there is no possibility of color overlap where I don't want it.

The problem is that one face that should be a solid color is appearing like TV screen static of red, gray, and black even though it should be a solid red. It shows up this way in both the UV texture editor window and in the blender viewport. It also stays the weird grainy texture if it is rendered out.

I tried deleting and recreating the problem face. I tried removing, changing, and re-baking the texture. I tried separating and reattaching the problem zone. I tried creating a new UV unwrap. I tried creating a new UV texture. Still the issue persists.

Has anyone had an issue like this or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

[image: This highlighted face shows this color in the UV editor]

This highlighted face shows up as this color in the UV editor

[image: But this is what that face shows up as in the texture viewport window. Not the same and I don't know why or how to fix it]

But this is what that face shows up as in the texture viewport window. Not the same and I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: Try to provide screenshots, or upload the .blend file and add the link to your questions.

Comment: In addition to what @Georges said: Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136554/edit) at the bottom of your question and [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). If you want to upload your file, please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add the given link to your question.

Comment: From my experience, this is probably because of one of the following reasons, first, you have an object with identical faces on another layer that is visible, second, you have a normal map attached to your shader, this sometimes happen when you import an fbx with material from another software, third, you have duplicate faces here which I don't think it's the case here, since you already deleted the face, forth, you have a Custom Split Normals Data in your object, again this mostly happens when you import a mesh from another software, mostly fbx.